# What is an exact evaluation function?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, evaluation, chess

I've been searching for hours and I haven't been able to come up with a decent definition of "exact evaluation function".

Preferably with regards to chess AI, I'd like to know what an exact evaluation function and how (and if) it differs from a heuristic evaluation function. Personally, I thought evaluation functions were just functions to evaluate future states based on the current state. I didn't realise they were broken down into separate categories.

Any help would be appreciated!

~Ray

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where did you come across this terminology?

When I learned about this, there are two type of approaches

1. Evaluation function = Heuristic evaluation function
2. Search techniques

**(Heuristic) evaluation functions** are algorithms that select moves based on evaluating the next moves based on a set of heuristic and doesn't attempt to explore the game tree/possible future states. These functions are fast and does reasonably well, but may not give you the best solution in all cases.

**Search techniques** try to "pre-play" the game by evaluating the future states (game tree search) and may use also use heuristic to prone bad choices or speed things up. They theoritically can make a **exact and perfect** choice, but are slow.

Comment: Well it is part of some homework, but doing a little bit of digging, I have found it referenced in a few papers (and I really mean "few") such as section 4.2 of the following paper: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.136.7661&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Seems like the author is not using standard terminology here, rather he is referring to some of his heuristics that are very strong that they guarantee the best solutions in some case (ie "prune" the game tree to without exploring it.)